# React 16.7 protected routes

Tags: reactjs, routes

I want to protect routes and make them available only for authenticated users.
the problem is that I know if the user is authenticated or not after doing a fetch() and updating the state in the **context** (and that takes some time)

I want to redirect users to /login when the fetch is complete and the context state isAuthenticated = false

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { MyContext } from './Context'

...

<MyContext.Consumer>
    {(context) => (

        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact strict component={Homepage}/>
            <Route path="/this-is-a-protected-route" exact strict component={Admin}/>
            <Route path="/login" exact strict component={Login}/>
        </Switch>

    )}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

this is the context

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext()

export class MyProvider extends Component {

    state = {
        'isAuthenticated': false,
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        fetch('/authenticated')
            .then(
                function(response) {
                    response.json().then(function(data) {
                        this.setState({'isAuthenticated': true})
                    });
                }
            )
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('fetch error', error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MyContext.Provider value={{
                isAuthenticated: this.state.isAuthenticated
            }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </MyContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Ideally I will be redirected to /login only after hitting /this-is-a-protected-route and the state.isAuthenticated = false (but this is the default value!)

I removed some code for brevity so we can focus on the problem. Hope you understand thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can render protected routes only if user authenticated

```
{context.isAuthenticated ? 
   <Route path="/this-is-a-protected-route" exact strict component={Admin}/> :
   <Redirect to='/login' />
}
```

Private routes can be moved to separate component.

More details and examples [here](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/).

Comment: That blog entry is the one I used - and it works well.